# Где указатель хранит значение

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Если указатель хранит адресс ячейки, то где хранится само значение?? например где хранится число 5?

```
int *b = new int(5)
```

Comment: Где-то в куске памяти, называемом кучей (heap), а где конкретно — это решают текущий менеджер памяти и операционная система независимо от вас

Comment: Само значение - хранится в ячейке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатель хранит адрес ячейки, в которой должно храниться какое - то значение (Как верно подсказал мне пользователь [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim), должно, но не всегда соблюдает это правило :) ). Когда нужно получить значение, программа смотрит адрес, находящийся в указателе, а потом извлекает значение по адресу, который был в нём. Всё просто.

EDIT, как говорится: адрес, который находится в указателе разный при каждом новом запуске программы. Он непостоянный. Существует специальная функция - аллокатор, которая и выделяет память под ячейку, на которую будет ссылаться указатель.

Comment: allocator это как бы не программа.

Comment: остальные ошибки сами исправите? или также подсказать?

Comment: Ну да, буду благодарен. Извините.

Comment: тогда проще просто удалить все сообщение:) смотрите, первое же предложение "Указатель хранит адрес ячейки, но не просто ячейки, а ячейки, в которой хранится само значение" - указатель просто хранит адрес. А что будет по этому адресу... иногда и программист не знает.

Answer (score 0):

В случае выделения памяти оператором new память под значение выделяется в специальной области памяти, называемой кучей. А в указатель соответсвенно записывается адрес этого значения. Не стоит забывать освобождать память выделенную в куче, поскольку это может привести к утечке памяти: значение в куче будет храниться пока не вызовется оператор `delete`. 
При объявлении переменной `int a = 5` значение будет храниться в стеке и при выходе из функции выделенная память освободится автоматически.